# When using a range to colour cells, they go black instead of intended colour

Tags: excel, vba, range, background-color

When using the line "Col_Range = "A1" & ":" & Col_Letter & "1" " to set the range that I will be highlighting, the alternate cells become black instead of the indended colour. But when I use just Rows(Counter).Interior.Color without defining a range, the entire row becomes the intended colour, no issue. Not sure why the colour comes out as black when without the range it works fine.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Counter, No_Of_Rows, Last_Delete, No_Of_Cols As Long
Dim Col_Letter, Col_Range As String

No_Of_Rows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
No_Of_Cols = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Counter = 7
Last_Delete = 1
Col_Letter = Chr(No_Of_Cols + 64)
Col_Range = "A1" & ":" & Col_Letter & "1"

Do While Counter <= No_Of_Rows
    If Cells(Counter, 1) = "Delete" Then
        Rows(Counter).Range(Col_Range).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 51, 0)
        Last_Delete = Last_Delete + 1
    ElseIf Cells(Counter, 1) = " " Then
        Rows(Counter).Range(Col_Range).Interior.Color = Rows(Counter - 1).Interior.Color
    Else
        If Last_Delete = 1 Then
            If Rows(Counter - 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
                Rows(Counter).Range(Col_Range).Interior.Color = RGB(221, 217, 196)
            Else
                Rows(Counter).Range(Col_Range).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            End If
        Else
            If Rows(Counter - Last_Delete).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
                Rows(Counter).Range(Col_Range).Interior.Color = RGB(221, 217, 196)
                Last_Delete = 1
            Else
                Rows(Counter).Range(Col_Range).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                Last_Delete = 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    Counter = Counter + 1
    
    Loop

End Sub
```

[Correct colouring but without range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0IU2.png)
[Colouring with the range showing black colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08zk0.png)

Comment: If all the cells in the row are not the same colour, then `Rows(Counter - 1).Interior.Color` will return null.